# How to solve the equation $(1-e^{-αa})(1-e^{-βa}) = 1/2$ for a?

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, exponential-function, problem-solving

Here is what I tried:
$(1-e^{-αa})(1-e^{-βa}) = 1/2$   implies $e^{-ln(2)} -e^{-βa} -e^{-αa} + e^{-a(β+α)} = 0$
But from here I don't know how to get the value of "a", any help ?

Comment: Letting $x=e^{-a}$, you are essentially solving $(1-x^\alpha)(1-x^\beta)=1/2.$ Not very promising for a closed form solution in general, even if $\alpha,\beta$ are positive integers. A numerical approach can help though.

Comment: You can reduce further into $(x-1)(x^r-1)=\frac12$ to get $x^{r+1}-x^r-x+\frac12=0$

Comment: @TymaGaidash Yes thanks for noting

Answer (score 1):

With [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem):

$$(x^r-1)(x-1)=\frac12\implies x=\frac12+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}(x^{r+1}-x^r)^n}{dx^{n-1}}\right|_{x=\frac12}$$

Using the binomial theorem, substituting $x=\frac12$, [factorial power $u^{(v)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower), and [the regularized Gauss hypergeometric $_2\tilde {\text F}_1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Hypergeometric2F1Regularized) function gives:

$$(x^r-1)(x-1)=\frac12\implies x=\frac12+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\binom nm(rn+m)^{(n-1)}\frac{(-1)^{n-m}}{n!} 2^{n-rn-m}=\boxed{\frac12+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(rn)!(-1)^n}{n!2^{(r-1)n}}\,_2\tilde{\text F}_1\left(-n,rn+1;(r-1)n+2;\frac12\right)}$$

[**Shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28x%5Ee-1%29%28x-1%29-1%2F2%2Cx%3D0.5%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28%28-1%29%5E%28-m+%2B+n%29+2%5E%28-1+-+m+%2B+n+-+e+n%29+*binomial%28n%2C+m%29+*factorialpower%28%28m+%2B+e+n%29%2C+-1+%2B+n%29%29%2F%28n%21%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C10%7D%5D) and both sums are interchangeable when $m$’s upper limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Maybe there is an integral representation